# ARKit ARSession sometimes not pausing before app is backgrounded

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am pausing ARKit every time my app is backgrounded via session.pause() on applicationWillResignActive.

I recently noticed some occasional high background battery usage of users, and now have occasionally witnessed the behavior where when the app is backgrounded, I get a bunch of these messages in the console :

2018-07-25 16:18:57.691271-0700 Neon[6918:1740969] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)
2018-07-25 16:18:57.691374-0700 Neon[6918:1740969] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)
2018-07-25 16:18:57.691425-0700 Neon[6918:1740969] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)
2018-07-25 16:18:57.692061-0700 Neon[6918:1740674] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)
2018-07-25 16:18:57.692100-0700 Neon[6918:1740674] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)

When I look at the energy and cpu usage, they are off the charts. But, other times, I do not get these messages and the cpu / energy usage is minimal.

My thought is that the pause is not completing before the app is backgrounded. I updated my app to use a backgroundTask to pause the ARSession object, but I am still observing the occasional behavior.

Any thoughts as to what may be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks as though this was a case of backgrounding the app while ARKit was still initializing, so the pause had no affect. Furthermore, when it finished initializing, it would run ARKit in the background, generating those GPU errors about not being able to run in the background and eating up battery.